# Is it OK to use MS Fakes shims with NSubstitute mocks?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute, microsoft-fakes

We are using [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.com/) to mock external objects for our unit tests. However many legacy classes are not called via interfaces and can't be easily replaced with mocks.

I've considered to use [Microsoft Fakes](http://richonsoftware.cloudapp.net/post/2012/04/05/Using-Stubs-and-Shim-to-Test-with-Microsoft-Fakes-in-Visual-Studio-11.aspx), but according to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677445/mock-framework-vs-ms-fakes-frameworks/9684782#9684782)  for the question ["Mock framework vs MS Fakes frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677445/mock-framework-vs-ms-fakes-frameworks/9684782#9684782)"

> " if you're already using a more full-featured mocking framework, you
>   might feel like there are some important pieces missing from Fakes
>   stubs."

Would it be possible to use MS Fakes shims  with NSubstitute mocks in the same tests?

Should we expect any compatibility problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. I've been using Shims together with NSubstitute for several months. It work fine both locally and on build server. The only trouble is Resharper test runner does not work with Shims, so we have to use VisualStudio's test runner instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to use Shims with mocking frameworks.

Comment: Do you have any experience with mixing Shims and NSubstitute? Can you share any tips, problems and workarounds. Or everything will work "as is"?

Comment: I have been successfully doing this with RhinoMocks. I personally like their mocking and stubbing over what the Fakes framework provides. However Shims are a nice additional tool to have.