# HOW to use MS Fakes shims with NSubstitute mocks?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, microsoft-fakes, nsubstitute

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839158/is-it-ok-to-use-ms-fakes-shims-with-nsubstitute-mocks) addressed the "can", without showing "how".  I am stuck at getting it up and running.  Can any one provide an example?  I tried

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
  public abstract Counter Counter { get; }
  public int abstract Foo(int n);
  public virtual int Foo(string s)
  {
    return Foo(Counter.Count(s));
  }          
}
```

I'd like to mock Foo(string s), which depends on the abstract property Counter.  The reason I want to mock Foo(string s) is because I don't want to provide definitions for Counter and Foo(int n) since only Foo(string s) is used by the verification code.

Approach 1:

```
var sub = Substitute.For<MyClass>();
ShimMyClass.AllInstances.Func1Int32 = ... ; // alternate behavior for testing
VerifyLogic(sub);
```

Approach 2:

```
var sub = Substitute.For<MyClass>();
var shim = new ShimMyClass(sub)
{
   Func1Int32 = ... ; // alternate behavior for testing
};
VerifyLogic(shim.Instance);
```

Neither one worked, the original class code is called instead of the shim code.  Thanks.

Comment: Show us the definition of the class, especially the method you're trying to mock. (it might be that you're getting caught because NSubstitute can only mock the behaviour of virtual methods.)

Comment: @ClickRick I provided the class definition.  Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you've found your answer on the NSub mailing list - something about `Counter.Count` being an internal method?

Comment: @ClickRick Yes.  I will provide an answer here later for documentation purpose if nobody submits an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the library that contains the class to be tested is Lib.

```
namespace Lib
{
public interface Counter { int Count(string s); }

public abstract class AbstractClass : AbstractParent
{
    internal int Value { get; set; }

    public abstract int Foo(int x);
    public int Foo(string s) { return Foo(Counter.Count(s)); }
}

public abstract class AbstractParent
{
    internal abstract Counter Counter { get; }
}
}
```

Locate Lib in the References of the Test project.  Select "Add Fakes Assembly".

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void AbstractMethod()
    {
        var instance = Substitute.For<AbstractClass>();

        using (ShimsContext.Create())
        {
            var instance = Substitute.For<AbstractClass>();

            Lib.Fakes.ShimAbstractClass.AllInstances.FooString =
                (_, s) => 1999;

            Assert.AreEqual(1999, instance.Foo("hello"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you'll flesh out the explanation with more of a "why" as well, I'll upvote it.

Comment: @ClickRick Not sure what you mean?  I'd be happy to improve the answer if it's not clear.