# Mocking concrete object properties with no setter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm testing a service that interfaces with a third-party system. The method exposed by the API returns objects that look something like this:

```
public class Thing
{
    public string Name { get {...} }
    public string Description { get {...} }

    public Thing(string someUri)
    {
        /* Do some secret internal stuff and
           populate all my properties. */
    }
}
```

I need to mock these properties in order to test that my service behaves correctly according to the objects returned.

The objects are instances of a concrete class that does not implement any interfaces that I can mock. The backing fields of these properties are set in the constructor of `Thing`, which takes a URI, goes off and fetches the object in some tightly-coupled third-party system and presumably sets the backing fields directly.

All of this means that I have no way to mock the properties - I can't set them directly, I can't mock an interface and I can't mock out the constructor dependencies and set the properties that way (which would diminish the usefulness of my tests anyway).

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using VS2012.2 or VS2013 in either Premium or Ultimate Edition, [shims](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549176.aspx) should get you what you need. They allow for "shimming" properties and constructors, ideally only for scenarios like the one you find yourself in (third-party library that doesn't use interfaces).

After adding a Fakes assembly for your library in your unit test project, you'd do something like this in your unit test:

```
using (ShimsContext.Create())
{
    ShimThing.ConstructorString = (@this, value) => {
        var shim = new ShimThing(@this) {
            NameGet = () => "Your Desired Name",
            DescriptionGet = () => "Your Desired Description"
        };
    };

    //do whatever you need to do that creates a Thing object
}
```

I wrote this example without actually trying it out, so the syntax of the ShimThing constructor might be slightly off.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Shims (build into visual studio) to fake a `Thing`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx

Comment: Note that Fakes and Shims require Visual Studio Premium or Ultimate. Another, cheaper option is [TypeMock](http://www.typemock.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You could just wrap the Thing -- this probably isn't the answer you're looking for because it will involve changes to the application code to support your unit testing, but it will result in a more loosely coupled code base and might make your life easier in the long run.

Create a `ThingWrapper` class that takes a `Thing` as a constructor argument and whose properties call the getters on the wrapped `Thing` instance. You can then

- mark these properties as `virtual` and mock the wrapper directly (less code)
- or have the wrapper implement an interface code against that interface (probably better).

Hope this helps, sorry if I'm just stating the obvious :/

Comment: Thanks for your answer Joe - unfortunately, though, what may not be obvious from my question is that the service under test is effectively already the middle-tier wrapper you're describing!

Comment: Fair enough. If it's the abstraction layer itself then it may be not be worth unit testing; a BDD type integration test might be more appropriate. I'm a little dubious about Fakes, not least because they're limited for VS Premium/Ultimate Edition. Some interesting discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11654698/332868