# How to unit-test this method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-4.5, moq, mstest

I have a method and it is also the method that I am trying to write a test for:

```
public IPlayerResponse GetPlayerStats(IPlayerRequest playerRequest)
{
    string playerId = playerRequest.PlayerId;

    string requestUri = playerId + "/evaluate";

     var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUri)
                                {
                                    Content = new StringContent
            (JsonConvert.SerializeObject(playerRequest),
             System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
            "application/json")
          };

      var response = _client
    .SendAsync(request, CancellationToken.None)
    .Result;
     var responseContent = response.
    Content
    .ReadAsStringAsync()
    .Result;



    var playerResponseModel =    
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PlayerResponseModel>(responseContent);
    var playerResponse = _mapper
.Map<IPlayerResponse>(playerResponseModel);

return playerResponse;
 }
```

The request interface:

```
public interface IPlayerRequest
    {
        IEnumerable<IPlayerStatsItem> Items { get; set; }
        string PlayerId { get; set; }
    }
```

I plan to write a test for this method and send the sample data for `IPlayerRequest` to get the response against a deployed end point. I have the TestSetup ready for hitting the endpoint.

What is the ideal way to mock the `IPlayerRequest` and populate it with some data to get a response?

Answer (score 1):

There is another syntax ([Moq functional specifications](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/old-style-imperative-mocks-vs-moq-functional-specifications/)) for setting up mock for cases like this:

```
var mockRequest = Mock.Of<IPlayerRequest>(
    r =>
    r.PlayerId == "MOCKID" &&
    r.Items == new List<IPlayerStatsItem>()); //or whatever needed);
```

There is also `Mocks.Of<T>`, so instead of using `r.Items ==  new List` you can do `r.Items == Mocks.Of<IPlayerStatsItem>()`. This will produce infinite list of mocks.

Answer (score 0):

In your calling method in the test setup just make a private class.

```
private class PlayerRequest : IPlayerRequest
{
    //hard code your test values you are passing in
    public string Name {get; private set;}
    public PlayerRequest() {
         Name = "MockName";
    }
}
```

then call:

```
var response = obj.GetPlayerStatus(new PlayerRequest());
```

edited to add the moq version if that is what you were trying to use:

```
var mockRequest = new Mock<IPlayerRequest>();
mockRequest.SetupGet(pr => pr.Name).Returns("MOCKNAME");

var response = obj.GetPlayerStatus(mockRequest.Object);
```

Answer (score 0):

I lack experience in using mocking framework as Moq or RhinoMocks, something on MS fakes, which works pretty good for stubbing(mocking) & shimming

If you have Visual Studio Premium or Ultimate you could always use MS fakes! (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx)

Simply stub the interface you're trying to replace with the stub, which is explained in the post.

U can then use it as follows :

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestSomething()
{
    // Arrange
    // Stub for PlayerRequest
    StubIPlayerRequest playerRequest = new StubIPlayerRequest
    {
        ItemsSetIEnumerableOfIPlayerStatsItem = items => { }, // Setters do nothing in this example.
        ItemsGet = () => new List<StubIPlayerStatsItem>(), // Also stubbed the other interface here, not required.
        PlayerIdGet = () => "Returns a string",
        PlayerIdSetString = s => { }
    };

    // Act

    // Assert whatever you need.
}
```

It's a pretty easy and straightforward framework for stubbing and shimming if you need in it your unit testing without downloading libraries.

Some interesting discussions on differences  -- > [Mock framework vs MS Fakes frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677445/mock-framework-vs-ms-fakes-frameworks)

HTH.